# How do I retrieve the string value of XmlEnum "Name"?

Tags: c#, xml, string, enums, mapping

I am new to XmlEnum property. I am working on a project written in C#. I have an enum class and I wanted to map each enum to a string value. So, for example, one of the enums is:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
   ...,
   [XmlEnum(Name = "Failed")]
   Failure = -1,
   ...
}
```

My question is, in my code in a .cs file how do I retrieve the string value of the enum Failure? How do I get this string with "Failed"?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
using System.Reflection;   
using System.Xml.Serialization;

string value=MyEnum.Failure.GetType()
                    .GetMember(MyEnum.Failure.ToString())
                    .FirstOrDefault()
                    ?.GetCustomAttribute<XmlEnumAttribute>()?.Name;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).